# Passing value from GUI Test to API Test

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to pass a value from GUI solution to API solution in UFT (I am a bit new to UFT)
 The flow is like

```
Start 

 GUI Test

 API Test

End
```

What I'v tried:

```
TestArgs(base64)=base64Encoded
```

and

```
Parameter(base64)=base64Encoded
```

base64 is the outparam I created from the properties pane of 'End' of GUI test.

Here base64 is giving me null after I assign using either of the above way

Is there any specific way to assign the value? Is this the correct way to pass a  value from GUI solution to the API solution

Comment: [**This**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/GUI_API_Integration_Use-Case_Scenario_Parameter_Passing.htm) link will help you get going.

Comment: is `base64` a variable that contains the name of the argument or the actual name of the argument? If the latter then it should be a string `"base64"`.

Comment: base64 is the output variable name that I defined in the 'End'section properties of GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the soultion:

1 . Define a Inparam in the API test in the Start section.
2. while calling the API from GUI ,pass the variable from GUI test like

```
RunAPITest "Demoservice" ,variable
```

3.Assign the Inparam to the proper tag in the service in API test. Now the value in variable will go to Inparam  and eventually to the assigned tag in the service call

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that you want to remember is that you will be creating a GUI test that will call an API test. You are able to save output parameters from the GUI test and then call your API test. You can use the article below to pass the parameters stored in the GUI test as an input parameter.

```
Start GUI test

 Save GUI Parameter(s)

 Call API test with "parameter(s) from Datatable" defined in the input parameters of the API test

End GUI test
```

Please use this article to get a feel for how to call API tests with parameters:

http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/GUI_API_Integration_Use-Case_Scenario_Parameter_Passing.htm

Comment: "2.After you create the parameter, you must link the test output parameter to the Get step output.

Click the Link to data source button  in the Test Input/Output Parameters tab, and then select the Get steps from the Available steps option. "

The above step I have to do in GUI Test . When I set the outparameter in GUI test End section. I don't get a link to data source button. Meanwhile when I do the same in API test , I am getting the link to data source button.

Comment: As you said I used 'Save 'outparam' ' after assigning value to the 'outparam' that I defined in the end section . Then also the same was not visible for me to assign to inParam defined in the start properties of API test